# Opacity on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a toggle button to allow user to select 1 or 2 rows

So when user click on the id it will remove or add the class and show diferents rows, so i need to add an opacity on the toggle button, how?, i need to show an opacity on the actual selected toggle button.

```js
    jQuery("#one-row").click(function () {
                        $('.product-list').removeClass('-two-columns');
                        $('.product-list').addClass('-one-columns');
                    });
    jQuery("#two-rows").click(function () {
                        $('.product-list').removeClass('-one-columns');
                        $('.product-list').addClass('-two-columns');
                    });
```

```css
    .toggle-one{
        background-image: url(images/toggle_1.svg);
        width: 30px;
        height: 10px;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .toggle-two{
        background-image: url(images/toggle_2.svg);
        width: 30px;
        height: 10px;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-rows" style="top: 118px;
        right: 30px;
        position: absolute;">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="toggle-one "  id="onw-row">
                          
                        </div>
                    </li> 
                     - 
                    <li style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="toggle-two" id="two-rows">
                          
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: Where is the `.product-list` element?

Comment: Its a cms class, not added by me.

Comment: I believe @ScottMarcus was referring to the HTML element having the `.product-list` class.

Comment: I dont have access to the html that has the product list, its a cms core file.

Comment: Even if that HTML is added dynamically, you can open your browser's development tools after its been loaded (F12) and copy the constructed HTML from there to post here. We need to be able to see all the relevant code to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, add two lines each for the buttons similar to this:

```
jQuery("#one-row").click(function () {
  $('.product-list').removeClass('-two-columns');
  $('.product-list').addClass('-one-columns');
  $("#one-row").css("opacity", "1");
  $("#two-rows").css("opacity", "0.3");                   
});
jQuery("#two-rows").click(function () {
  $('.product-list').removeClass('-one-columns');
  $('.product-list').addClass('-two-columns');
  $("#one-row").css("opacity", ".0.3");
  $("#two-rows").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

Comment: he has a typo in id #onw-row

Comment: @pegla so what? The whole snippet (edited by someone else) doesn't display any meaningful result - I was only referring to the very first version of the question.